# On a `ul`, Desktop vertical scroll works but mobile's touch scroll doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one `ul` tag with `max-height: 180px` and `overflow: auto` styles.

This `ul` will have more `li` tags added dynamically (something like add `li` upon button click).

**Issue**: I can perfectly scroll list items if more `li` tags are added which doesn't fit in the max height of container. But, this is happening only in desktop. When I try same from my mobile chrome browser, it doesn't scroll.

Tried following, but no luck:

- `z-index`, value is some 1000000 or above.
- `overflow: scroll`, `overflow-y: scroll`, `overflow: auto`
- overlapping by other elements, none
- `<body>` tag had `overflow: hidden`, tried removing that, too

**Question**: What more should I debug? Couldn't find many solutions/documentations around this.

Sharing repro steps below, but, do not wish to get direct solution from your efforts. Only need some pointers to proceed.

Here is my test site with repro: https://interesting-my-store.myshopify.com/products/15mm-combo-wrench , open this page in mobile and click on red button with heart icon in it. A modal will pop up. Click "Create new collection" some 10 times and you will see that list won't scroll in mobile. But if you use desktop or use desktop debugger, it will scroll.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can try to help?

Comment: Hmm thats a good idea. Working on it. Thanks for sharing link.

Comment: Couldn't repro properly, but here is my test site with repro: https://interesting-my-store.myshopify.com/products/14k-dangling-pendant-earrings-1 , open this page in mobile and click on red button with heart icon in it. A modal will open up. Click "Create new collection" some 10 times and you will see that list won't scroll in mobile. But if you use desktop or use desktop debugger, it will scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found fix myself.

Issue was: Scroll was blocked with preventDefault() somewhere in my code.

Debugging: Found issue by adding "touchmove" event to my div container. Logged event data when I scrolled from my phone (via USB debugging on desktop). It showed me `defaultPrevented: true`. Thats where I realized preventDefault might be causing it. Looked for it in my code, and found that I had applied preventDefault on `touchmove` event at one place.

Removed that preventDefault and tried again and it worked.

Lesson learned:

1. If UI can be scrolled in desktop, it will be too in mobile unless blunder like above. No separate css or JS needed for scroll on mobiles.
2. If CSS is not giving away anything, go and look in JS too and don't ignore it thinking what JS has to do with touch screen.

Comment: So I lost about half my sanity, until I found this answer. For me the `touchmove` event was being prevented by `@headlessui/vue` version `<1.7.3` in the Dialog component. After upgrading to `1.7.3` my issue was solved.

Comment: Extra information: I used `getEventListeners(document)` and `getEventListeners(document.body)` in a chromium browser to find out which listener was calling `event.preventDefault()`.